# Excel VBA: Opening embedded picture (Either to a form's picture control or external application)

Tags: vba

I have an excel sheet with a bunch of embedded images. How do I open one of the embedded images either in the default image viewer (for the system) or in a VBA Form's picture control?

I tried the .Verb for OLEObjects, but that doesn't seem to work with pictures.

Comment: Where is the code you have tried so far and what error messages you are getting?

Comment: Maybe this might help https://danny.fyi/embedding-and-accessing-a-file-in-excel-with-vba-and-ole-objects-4d4e7863cfff